# How much do characteristic classes fail to characterize bundles?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, cohomology, characteristic-classes, gauge-theory

Given a group $G$, let $E \to B$ be a principal $G$-bundle. It is
well-known that when $B$ is a nice enough topological space (e.g.
CW-complex), such a thing corresponds to a connected component of
$Hom(B,BG)$. So say the bundle corresponds to $[f] \in
\pi_0(Hom(B,BG))$. The characteristic classes of the bundle is
therefore the pull-backs $f^\star(\omega)$ where $\omega \in
H^\star(BG;\mathbb{Z})$.

**Question**: I am interested in to what extent characteristic
classes fail to characterize bundles.

As $B$ varies, I believe the question is equivalent to

**Question'**: To what extent does the cohomology ring
$H^\star(BG;\mathbb{Z})$ fail to characterize $BG$ up to
homotopic equivalence.

It is well-known that taking cohomology does forget much
information. And for good enough spaces still, one needs to
consider the cochain complex as an $E_\infty$ algebra. Moreover,
any (good enough) space $X$ is equivalence to $B\Omega X$, so I
need to restrict my questions more.

**Question''**: What can we say about Question' for G being the
most popular groups, e.g. finite groups, compact Lie groups,
loop group of $S^1$.. etc.

Comment: Consider the case when $G$ is a complex Lie group $\textbf{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, so that all characteristic classes are in even cohomological degree, yet $B$ is an odd-dimensional sphere with vanishing cohomology of even degree $>0$.

Comment: Yes. With $G$ fixed there's always very bad $B$ that makes everything vanish. In such case characteristic classes do not see anything unfortunately.. So I changed my question to question' to see how they fail for general $B$. - But anyway, are there many interesting $GL_n(C)$ bundle over odd-dimensional spheres? That should correspond to the odd homotopy groups of $BGL_n(C)$ - aren't they trivial?

Comment: “. . . aren’t they always zero?”  The third homotopy group of a nontrivial semisimple complex Lie group is always nonzero.  A very useful table was compiled by my Stony Brook colleague Alexander Abanov: http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/~abanov/Teaching/Spring2009/Notes/abanov-cpA1-upload.pdf

Comment: For $G=SO(n)$ Euler and Pontryagin classes determine a $G$-bundle up to finite ambiguity. I wonder what happens for other connected Lie groups $G$.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek If I am not being silly, $G$-bundles for arbitrary G are determined up to finite ambiguity by these integral characteristic classes, because $G$ is rationally a product of Eilenberg MacLane spaces.

Comment: @mme, if this is how you define "characteristic classes" then yes, this is what it boils down to. The case when $G$ isn't connected (e.g. discrete) is less clear to me.

Comment: What is your notion of characteristic class? (I am interested in whatever more general problem you have in mind.) I agree about disconnected G, it is hard to see what one can say.

Comment: @Jason Starr: the homotopy groups of a Lie group are not the same as the homotopy groups of its classifying space!

Comment: @NicolasTholozan.  Indeed not, there is a degree shift in homotopy groups.  There are many examples of nonzero, odd-degree homotopy groups of classifying spaces, as one can see from the useful table in my previous comment.

Comment: Your Question' is true for finite groups: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042568

Comment: @mme every group $G$ is rationally a product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, but the relevant question is whether $BG$ is. This is true for Lie groups, but not general groups. For example, set $G=\Omega S^2$, so $BG=S^2$.

Comment: @BenWieland I see, thanks for the clarifying example. I will leave my comments in case someone else can learn from my mistake.

Comment: I am a bit too lazy to formulate this throughly enough for an answer: Classical characteristic classes (Stiefel Whitney classes, Euler class, Chern classes and I think even Pontryagin classes) can be defined in terms of primary (!) obstructions to certain lifting problems (or some "algebraic modification" of that) and as such they can't control the full behaviour of the vector bundle, but only the gluing data for cells of a fixed dimensions, while the gluing of the higher dimensional cell will not be captured by the characteristic classes.

Comment: @ThorbenK Yes. The higher obstructions are harder in this direction. I wonder if we can understand this problem by not taking cohomology of $BG$ - because in principal everything we need is in $[X,BG]$.

Answer (score 5):

I am just posting my comment as an answer.  This question comes up fairly often for algebraic geometry students who are learning about moduli spaces of stable vector bundles, particularly in the case that the base projective manifold has dimension one or two.  In both of these cases, if we fix the first Chern class and let the second Chern class increase, the moduli spaces are eventually connected (or empty), reflecting the fact that there are no discrete invariants other than the first and second Chern classes.

However, it is not true that the homotopy-theoretic information of a vector bundle is faithfully encoded by the Chern classes.  Indeed, there are many nonvanishing, odd-degree homotopy groups of classifying space $B\text{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, cf. the following link.

[http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/~abanov/Teaching/Spring2009/Notes/abanov-cpA1-upload.pdf](http://felix.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Eabanov/Teaching/Spring2009/Notes/abanov-cpA1-upload.pdf)

Since the cohomology of an odd-dimensional sphere is trivial in even degree $>0$, the Chern classes vanish for every complex vector bundle on an odd-dimensional sphere.

Comment: The link does not directly address $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$. The closest cases seems to be the classical ones (real compact Lie groups). Perhaps you mean that we can read off the homotopy groups of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ from those of them (and how)? In any case, thanks for the comment! I'm still pretty curious about how much info is lost in the process $G \mapsto H^\star(G;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @Student the maximal compact subgroups of GL(n,C) are isomorphic to U(n), and generally the inclusion of a maximal compact subgroup is a homotopy equivalence (here one can concretely see this by Gram-Schmidt); the table addresses the homotopy groups of U(n) and hence those of GL(n,C)

Answer (score 3):

For *discrete* $G$, the classifying space $BG$ carries the same homotopical information as $G$. On the other hand, the group cohomology $H^{\star}(BG;\mathbb Z)$ can vanish for non-trivial $G$, as it is known that acyclic groups exist. (However, note that there are no *finite* acyclic groups.)

Comment: What is the proof of your final sentence? Something like: if $G$ was acyclic, pick a faithful unitary representation, then a spectral sequence argument shows that the natural map $H^* U(n)/G \to H^* U(n)$ is an isomorphism; because the natural map $U(n) \to U(n)/G$ is a degree $|G|$ covering map and the top-degree cohomology is $\Bbb Z$, it follows that $|G| = 1$. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: I suppose that is the idea, yes. It is mentioned in the first few lines of this paper https://marc-culler.info/static/home/papers/HomologyFiniteGroup.pdf that proves the analogous statement for morphisms. Apparently it is due to Mazur, but unpublished.

Comment: I did not know this trick was due to Mazur. Thanks for the reference.